# Can't render out an array inside the data of my state

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, state

I have attached an image in which you can see the data in my state which I want to render out

```
    <Hero>
              {HeroesInfo.map((hero) => (
                <HeroCards
                  name={hero.localized_name}
                  type={hero.attack_type}
                  key={hero.id}
                  legs={hero.legs}
                  img={hero.img}
                  icon={hero.icon}
                />
              ))}
            </Hero>
```

here for each  object present in the array I want to pass this component called HeroCards and it works fine.
however as you might be able to see that there is that array of "roles" in  there
I tried to render it out using this logic =

`{HeroesInfo.roles.map((data) => ( <h1>for each role <h1>))}`

but this is giving me an error of cant map over undefined :(
im learning redux so this is my reducer now with my states

```
    const initState = {
      HeroesInfo: [],
      GamesUpcoming: [],
      GamesOld: [],
      GamesType: [],
      HeroesInfo2: [],
    };
    const HInfoReducer = (state = initState, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case "FETCH_HEROES":
          return {
            ...state,
    
            HeroesInfo: action.payload.HeroesInfo,
            HeroesInfo2: action.payload.HeroesInfo2,
            GamesUpcoming: action.payload.GamesUpcoming,
          };
    
        default:
          return { ...state };
      }
    };
    export default HInfoReducer;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you need to do:

```
{HeroesInfo.map((hero) => hero.map((data) => ( <h1>for each role <h1>)))}
```

or if it's part of the card? Then you need to pass the roles in

```
<HeroCards
     name={hero.localized_name}
     type={hero.attack_type}
     key={hero.id}
     legs={hero.legs}
     img={hero.img}
     icon={hero.icon}
     roles={hero.roles}
/>
```

and then in the card do:

```
{roles.map((role) => <h1>for each role</h1>)}
```

Comment: ok so I've tried the first approach before in a different div and it didn't worked, Gave me an error of "undefined again " but the second approach where you showed how you are mapping over the passed roles prop worked so yeah, Can you explain what happened here in brief? is it because since its an array inside of an array of object I had access the the array of roles and in the Card section I had to map over that array again? Also there is this problem where I cant display that png image in the data but jpg works fine. Thanks again though :)

Comment: The issue is that `HeroesInfo` doesn't have a `.roles` property at all.  So you need to first get an individual item from `HeroesInfo`, which *does*, and then map over *that* array.  So yes, you need two maps, one to map each hero to a card, and then another to map each of the heroes roles to an h1